# Sed regex match with variable endings is not matchng

Tags: linux, sed

I have file that in simple example looks like:

```
some_file_name{
something
otherthing2
otherthing3
}
```

How ever "some_file_name" can end with end of line, space or { so I need to match every variant. To further complicate things the some_file_name contains / so delimiter needs to be different... and in the end I need to replace "something" between the some_file_name{ and the next } so the result would be:

```
some_file_name{
something_replaced
otherthing2
otherthing3
}
```

I got as far:

```
sed -r "\%some_file_name\($\|[[:space:]]\|\{\)%,\%\}%{s/something/something_replaced/}" "file.txt"
```

( sed -r is mandatory )
My best gues the issue is somewhere here: `\($\|[[:space:]]\|\{\)` where I try to match the 3 possible endings ... but for life of me I can't figure it out what is missing.

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r "\%some_file_name($|[[:space:]]|\{)%,\%\}%{s/something/something_replaced/}" "file.txt"
```

`-r` (and `-E`, which is more portable, so whenever you can, choose this one) enables extended regular expressions. So you should neither escape the grouping parenthesis, nor the vertical bar, otherwise they are treated literally by sed.

Still confused? Consider this:

```
$ echo '(' | sed 's/(/X/'
X
$ echo '(' | sed -E 's/(/X/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: Unmatched ( or \(
$ echo '(' | sed -E 's/\(/X/'
X
```

Comment: I mentioned that the -r is mandatory, I had it working with -E cause that is more simple no need escape stuff as you mentioned, but I have to work with -r :(

Comment: @VladoPortos As I said, they are equivalent, so if it works with `-E`, should work with `-r`. But since you require it, I kept the `-r`.

Comment: `-r` is just the old GNU-sed-only equivalent of `-E` which works on OSX/BSD aed and newer versions of GNU sed.